# How to test Observable subscribe callback using jasmine?

Tags: angular, jasmine, angular9, jasmine2.0

I have an Angular9, Angular Material table similar to the ones in the docs.
https://material.angular.io/components/table/examples

The difference in my case is that I implemented a constructor in the table class as well as a custom datasource, etc. I am getting the data for my table inside the actual table class using a function called inside ngOnInit() and the called function basically subscribes to an observable coming from service and I don't really know how to test it and I need help.
[As you can see, --code-coverage is complaining that I didn't cover the subscribe callback. So how do I do that?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/inNAD.png)

Yes, the service is tested already so I separated the tests. Obviously I'm not gonna test the service in this component's testfile. I just don't get why this code is not covered/how to do it.
I am using TestBed, some code is already covered but I'm not including it so I don't make the question a astronomically long.

```
describe('MemeTableComponent', () => {
  let component: MemeTableComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<MemeTableComponent>;
  const inputData = flattenObjectArray(gatewayInfo);

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [MemeTableComponent],
      imports: [
        NoopAnimationsModule,
        MatPaginatorModule,
        MatSortModule,
        MatTableModule,
        HttpClientTestingModule
      ],
      providers: [
        MemeService
      ]
    }).compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MemeTableComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
    component.dataSource.data = inputData;
  });

  it('should compile', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Comment: You have to mock `DomainService` but I don't see it in your constructor which is strange. You have to mock `getAllFromApi` to return an observable.

Comment: If you take a second look at the photo in that link you'll see that the service is injected into the constructor for that table class. Also into the providers array for the test. The names are different MemeService =/= MSAPIoTDomainService(picture) because info leaks, I forgot to rename MSAPIoTDomainService in the picture. Consider them the same.

Comment: Before calling the first `fixture.detectChanges` in the `beforeEach`, get a handle on `domainService` with `TestBed.inject` and then do `spyOn(domainService, 'getData').and.returnValue(of([]))` (mock v inside of that array).